# Map Axis Numeric Values to Strings

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-charts, customization, google-drawings

I have time series data reviewing the quality of an item.  The ratings are on a 1-5 scale ranging from "Very Bad" to "Very Good".  How can I define this mapping so that instead of seeing marks for 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 on the Y-axis I instead see "Very Bad", "Poor", "OK", "Good", "Very Good"?

Seems like this ought to be doable.  The prefix/suffix options are just not able to do what's needed but they show that there's a need for some tweaking.  I wish I could just specify a formula to define the displayed value.

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: @user0 https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ovVtiQGU-XUqDdB_SihT0lwVknmclhuUX7IW-QDYzTg/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible directly but there is a workaround for that:

- enter in the editing of the chart
- select **Vertical axis**
- increase **Label font size** to gain some space
- change **Text color** for pure white to hide it
- go to **Insert**
- select **Drawing...**
- and add 5 drawings - then position them

[image: 0]

---

[image: 0]

**[demo spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-SGIA1MQzGUWvwWoytSH2_bfSkyrxdwzg5TC62KUbxI/edit#gid=150512338)**

Comment: Not an ideal solution, but it seems this is the only way for now.  Thanks!